# Calculus with little $o$ notation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

Let $f(x)$ be a smooth function for all $x \geq 0$ and suppose that it satisfies
$$f'(x) = o(x^\alpha)$$
as $x \to 0$ and for some $\alpha > 0$. Can we conclude that
$$
f(x) = c + o ( x^{1+\alpha}) ?
$$
I can prove this if $\alpha = 0$ almost trivially. In this case, we have $f'(x) = o(1)$ which implies that $f'(0) = 0$. By definition of derivative, we have
$$
f'(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = 0 
$$
But now, by definition of little-$o$ notation,
$$
f(x) - f(0) = o(x) \implies f(x) = f(0) + o(x).
$$
How do I extend such an argument for all $\alpha$? In fact, I will also be happy if there is a proof for $\alpha \in {\mathbb N}$.

---

Here is my attempt at a proof for the case $\alpha = 1$. I think if you agree that this proof is correct, then I can easily generalize this to all integer values of $\alpha$.

For $\alpha=1$, we have $f'(x) = o(x)$ so
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f'(x)}{x} = 0 
$$
Since $f'(0) = 0$, we can use L'Hôpital's rule which implies $f''(0) = 0$. We now use the following definition the second derivative
$$
f''(0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{2[f(x) - f(0)-xf'(0)]}{x^2}  = 0 
$$
That this definition of $f''(0)$ is true follows from L'Hôpital's rule. Now using the definition of little-$o$ notation and using $f'(0) = 0$ again, we find
$$
f(x) - f(0) = o(x^2) \implies f(x) = f(0) + o(x^2) . 
$$

---

Assuming I haven't made any serious error above, this type of argument clearly generalizes trivially for all $\alpha \in {\mathbb N}$.

Comment: Could you provide your workings for the $\alpha = 0$ case?

Comment: @LucaArmstrong - added.

Comment: @LucaArmstrong - added a proof for $\alpha=1$ which is easily generalizable to $\alpha  \in {\mathbb N}$. Is there anything incorrect there?

Comment: You do not need l'Hopital to conclude that the limit of a difference quotient is the differential quotient, as in $\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x}\to f''(0)$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann - I agree. That is simply the definition of $f''(0)$. Is the rest of the argument correct?

Comment: I think your attempt for $\alpha=1$ is correct, but I don't understand how you've assumed $f'(0)=0$ with the $\alpha=0$ case.  I think you'd need $\alpha$ to be strictly greater than zero as you have already stated.

Comment: Also I do have a solution for all values of $\alpha>0$ if you'd like me to include it.

Comment: @LucaArmstrong - In that case, $f'(x)=o(1)$ so it automatically means that $f'(0)=0$ right? By the very definition of little-$o$ $f'(x)=o(1) \implies \lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{1}=f'(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes, please! I'd love to see the proof. Thanks!

Comment: Yes sorry about that. I understand. I'll provide my answer in a minute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement $f'(x)=o(x^{\alpha})$ as $x\to 0$ is equivalent to saying that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a $\delta>0$ such that $|f'(x)|<\epsilon x^{\alpha}$ for all $x < \delta$. This means that for all $x\in[0, \delta)$

$$|f(x)-f(0)| = \left|\int_0^x{f'(t)~dt}\right| \le \int_0^x{\epsilon t^{\alpha}~dt} \le \epsilon x^{1+\alpha}$$

But since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily small, this shows that $f(x)=f(0)+o(x^{1+\alpha})$ as $x\to0$.

Comment: amazing! Thanks a lot for all your help.

Comment: Can I also get your help for this follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734233/calculus-with-little-o-notation-follow-up?

Answer (score 2):

One could use the extended mean value theorem
$$
\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x^{α+1}}=\frac{f'(z)}{(α+1)z^α}.
$$
As $0<z<x$ we get that $x\to 0$ implies $z\to0$ and the claim follows.

Comment: oh! Thank you!!

Comment: Can I also get your help for this follow up question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4734233/calculus-with-little-o-notation-follow-up?