# Calculus with little-o notation: Follow-up

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics

This question is a follow-up of [Calculus with little $o$ notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4727143/calculus-with-little-o-notation) where I asked if it was true that
$$
f'(x) = o (x^\alpha) \qquad \implies \qquad f(x) = f(0) + o(x^{\alpha+1}) \quad \forall \quad  \alpha > 0 ~ ?? \tag{1}
$$
where $f : [0,\infty) \to {\mathbb R}$ is a smooth function and we are taking the limit $x \to 0$. I got two great answers showing that this was indeed true. I have two follow-up questions:

1. I believe those two proofs can be extended trivially to the region $\alpha > -1$. Is this correct?
2. Can we generalize (1) to $\alpha < -1$ in some way? In particular, is the following true:
   $$
   f'(x) = o (x^\alpha) \qquad \implies \qquad f(x) = o(x^{\alpha+1}) \quad \forall \quad  \alpha \leq -1 ~ ?? \tag{2}
   $$
   where now $f:(0,\infty) \to {\mathbb R}$ is a smooth function.

---

EDIT: Apparently, if I don't add context for this question, the post will be closed. I'm certain the context won't help at all, but here goes.

I'm trying to solve the BPS equations in a $U(1)^3$ truncation of $N=8$ gauged supergravity in five dimensions and trying to understand the near horizon geometry of supersymmetric black holes with charged scalar hair (so-called hairy black holes). After a significant amount of simplification, I managed to boil my problem down to a set of 5 coupled ordinary differential equations for 5 functions. I am able to make progress towards my goal if equation (2) of the post holds (or some version thereof) and that's why I'm asking if such a theorem could possibly be true.

For example, one of the 5 differential equations is of the form
$$
(2 x U )' = H \sqrt{ 4 + \Phi^2 } . 
$$
I know that $H=r_+^2 + o(1)$ and $\Phi = C x^{-\alpha} + o(x^{-\alpha})$ for some $\alpha,r_+,C > 0$(as $x \to 0$ which is where the horizon of the black hole is located). Given this information, what can I deduce about the near-horizon behaviour of $U(x)$ (i.e. its behaviour as $x \to 0$)?

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391) + [please avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933), otherwise your post will be closed/deleted for lack of "context"

Comment: @AnneBauval - that's true. I thought the reverse implication was obviously true. I have edited the question now to be more correct. But can you explain why $\Longleftarrow$ is incorrect?

Comment: @AnneBauval - Would it be possible to give an example where (1) fails to hold in the $\Longleftarrow$ direction? I was trying to come with some example but am blanking out.

Comment: $f(x)=x^\beta\sin\frac1x$ where $\alpha+1<\beta\le\alpha+2.$  Unfortunately, it is not smooth at $0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval - thanks! Do you know if my equation (2) is possibly true? or maybe you can think of a counter-example? Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. And please see my 1st comment above.

Comment: @AnneBauval - I have no idea how adding the context could possibly help with the question, but I've included it as requested.

Comment: All your little $o$'s are as $x\to 0$?

Comment: @D.R. - yes!!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, Lutz Lehmann's argument still goes through for $\alpha>-1$: use the extended mean value theorem with $f \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ as in your question and $g \colon [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ given by $g(x)=x^{\alpha+1}$, noting that for each $x>0$, $f$ and $g$ are both continuous on $[0,x]$ and differentiable on $(0,x)$.
2. For $\alpha<-1$, a variant of Luca Armstrong's argument works: Suppose for a contradiction that $f'(x)$ is $o(x^\alpha)$ but $f(x)$ is not $o(x^{\alpha+1})$ as $x \to 0$. So we can find $C>0$ and a strictly decreasing sequence of values $x_n \to 0$ such that $|f(x_n)| \geq Cx_n^{\alpha+1}$ for all $n$; and we can then find $\delta>0$ such that $|f'(x)| \leq -\frac{\alpha+1}{2}Cx^\alpha$ for all $x \in (0,\delta]$. For all sufficiently large $n$,
   $$ |f(x_n)| \leq |f(x_n)-f(\delta)| + |f(\delta)| \leq \int_{x_n}^\delta |f'(x)| \, dx + |f(\delta)| < \tfrac{1}{2}Cx_n^{\alpha+1} + |f(\delta)|. $$
   So taking $n$ sufficiently large that $|f(\delta)| < \tfrac{1}{2}Cx_n^{\alpha+1}$, we have $f(x_n)<Cx_n^{\alpha+1}$, contradicting that $|f(x_n)| \geq Cx_n^{\alpha+1}$.

---

For $\alpha=-1$, your question 2 isn't really formulated correctly: just taking $f$ to be a non-zero constant would be a trivial counter-example. But even if we were to ask whether
$$
f'(x) = o (x^{-1}) \qquad \implies \qquad f(x) = O(1)
$$
with a big $O$ on the right side of the implication sign (meaning that it should be *easier* to fulfil), the answer would still be *no*: a counter-example is given by $f(x)=\log(-\log x)$ for $x$ close to $0$, where we have $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x\log x}$ for $x$ close to $0$.

The "corrected version" of Eq. (2) for $\alpha=-1$ is
$$
f'(x) = o (x^{-1}) \qquad \implies \qquad f(x) = o(-\log x).
$$
The proof is identical to the above proof for $\alpha<-1$ except replacing
$$ |f(x_n)| \geq Cx_n^{\alpha+1} \quad \text{with} \quad |f(x_n)| \geq -C\log x_n $$
and
$$ |f'(x)| \leq -\tfrac{\alpha+1}{2}Cx^\alpha \quad \text{with} \quad |f'(x)| \leq \tfrac{C}{2x}. $$

Comment: Thank you! This was really helpful.